# How to show that a subgroup of $A_5$ of order $10$ is in the normaliser of a Sylow $5$ subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

How to show that a subgroup of $A_5$ of order $10$ is in the normaliser of a Sylow $5$ subgroup of $A_5$?

I don't even know how to approach this problem other than to say let $D$ be a subgroup of $A_5$ of order $10$?

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\;n_p\;$ denotes the number of Sylow $\;p\,-$ subgroups, then

$$|A_5|=2^2\cdot3\cdot5\implies n_p\in\{\,1,6\,\}$$

and since $\;A_5\;$ is simple and it can't have no non-trivial normal subgroups , we must have $\;n_5=6\;$ .

But by Sylow Theorem's proofs we know that $\;n_p=[G:N_G(P_p)]\;,\;\;P\;$ any Sylow $\;p\,-$ subgroups, and thus

$$6=n_5=[A_5: N_{A_5}(P_5)]\implies |N_{A_5}(P_5)|=\frac{60}{10}=10$$

adn we're done (fill in the minor details left.)

Comment: Actually I do have a question. My question is this: http://imgur.com/a/Asvu1 I am asking about part e) but haven't you answered part f)? Do you have any hints for part g)? I think I will post separately.

Comment: @RyanS Not exactly: I've given you **the exact proof** that $\;|N_{A_5}(P_5)|=10\;$ . It is up to you that out of the only two possible groups of order 10 (up to isomorphism), the abelian (in fact, cyclic) one **cannot** be a subgroup of $\;A_5\;$ and thus $\;N_{A_5}(P_5)\cong D_{10}\;$ , the dihedral group of order ten.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the fact that $A_5$ is simple, and conclude that $\#Syl_5(A_5)=6$. Hence, if $S \in Syl_5(A_5)$, then by Sylow $|A_5:N_{A_5}(S)|=6$. Then you must show that there is only one isomorphy type of subgroups of order $10$.